# Creating a Columnstore Index

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes, columnstore

Is it possible to create a column store index on a table in sql which already has a clustered index & non clustered index over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE SimpleTable
(ProductKey [int] NOT NULL, 
OrderDateKey [int] NOT NULL, 
DueDateKey [int] NOT NULL, 
ShipDateKey [int] NOT NULL);
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cl_simple ON SimpleTable (ProductKey);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX noncl_simple ON SimpleTable(OrderDateKey);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX csindx_simple
ON SimpleTable
(OrderDateKey, DueDateKey, ShipDateKey);
GO
```

Comment: Hi nikolay, Thanks for replying to my query. I successfully created a non clustered columnstore index on my existing table that already has a row based clustered & a non clustered index. Can you please advice if i need to create a clustered columnstore index than do i need to drop my existing  row based clustered index first???